# Docker-Compose randomly assigned ports

Tags: docker, docker-compose, api-gateway

Probably a stupid simple question but I'm having trouble with docker-compose randomly assigning a port to a container.

I have all my services behind an API gateway and that gateway is the only service which should be mapped to the outside

The compose file looks like this

```
services:
    api.gateway:
        build:
          context: .
          dockerfile: API.Gateway/Dockerfile
        ports:
            - "80:80"

    api.products:
        build:
          context: .
          dockerfile: API.Products/Dockerfile
        ports:
            - "80"
```

when started 80 maps to 80 just fine for the gateway. But products service will randomly be assigned an external port which i dont want. I want all communication with that service to go through the api gateway.

Answer (score 1):

Since you dont want to access the products API from your host, then you do not need `ports` exposed on your host for it.

The API Gateway is exposed to your host. Then *that* will forward requests to the other container via the Docker network without going through your host network interface.